# Unable to get expected result from Lucee Mail Listener function

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I'm looking to learn MailListener concept in Lucee. Actually, below is the code that was mentioned in Lucee doc.

```
component {
    this.Name = "Lucee Mail";
    this.mail.listener=function() {
        systemOutput('--------------- function defined in Application.cfc ---------------',1,1);
        systemOutput(arguments.keyList(),1,1);
        systemOutput(detail,1,1);
    };
}
```

Using the above code, I can able to see the result on tomcat.

But, I used the below code.

```
component {
    this.Name = "Lucee Mail";
    this.mail.listener=function() {
        fileWrite('keyList.txt', arguments.keyList());
        fileWrite('details.txt', systemOutput(detail,1,1));
    };
}
```

Now, I can able to see KeyLists on the particular text file. But, couldn't able to see the detail on the particular file. I'm not sure why It's not working on fileWrite.

### My KeyList.txt file output

caller,created,detail,closed,lastExecution,advanced,tries,id,type,passed,remainingtries

### My details.txt file output

true

Comment: So what's the code that didn't give the "expected result"? Is FileRead a typo?

Comment: ... because FieldRead does the opposite of SystemOutput. The former *reads* information from a file, while the latter *writes*  data.

Comment: ... because FieldRead does the opposite of SystemOutput. The former *reads* information from a file, while the latter *writes*  data.

Comment: @Ageax Sorry for the delay reply. I have modified my questions.

Comment: @Ageax So, I don't need to use systemoutput inside of the filewrite. Right? I mean, like fileWrite('details.txt',detail);

Comment: (edit) No you don't need both, because they do the same thing, i.e. write to a file. The code is only logging key names because that is what you're telling it to do here: `arguments.keyList()`. Look into functions like `serializeJSON()`, or possibly `serialize()`, to generate a string representation of the structure that can be written to a file.